# How to request synthesis with a positive volume gain?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

The API for Google Cloud Text-to-speech provide an option to add/remove volume gain when requesting synthesis.

Link: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.texttospeech.v1#google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioConfig)

The field that enable that option is **volume_gain_db**

I'm using the RPC APIv1 (Google Text-to-Speech) on a project using the **Go** library.

The code is running from an instance inside Google Cloud virtual machine instance.

The API (Google Text-to-Speech) access is enabled and granted for that virtual machine.

Here is an example of a request:

```
import texttospeechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/texttospeech/v1"

// Setting up the client..

req := texttospeechpb.SynthesizeSpeechRequest{
    Input: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput{
        InputSource: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput_Ssml{Ssml: "Hello this is a test"},
    },
    Voice: &texttospeechpb.VoiceSelectionParams{
        LanguageCode: "en",
        SsmlGender:   texttospeechpb.SsmlVoiceGender_MALE,
    },
    AudioConfig: &texttospeechpb.AudioConfig{
        AudioEncoding: texttospeechpb.AudioEncoding_OGG_OPUS,
        VolumeGainDb: 6,
    },
}

// Making the request..
```

The current problem is that setting a positive gain ex: [0, 1, 6, 16]db, throws the following error:

```
Unable to get speech rpc error: 
code = InvalidArgument 
desc = Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Testing with negative value ex: [-6, -0.1, 0]db is working.

Testing with invalid positive/negative value ex: 20db/-100db is not working as expected.

```
Unable to get speech rpc error: 
code = OutOfRange 
desc = Out of range: valid volume_gain_db is between -96.0 and 16.0.
```

I would like to know if there is an option I need to enable somewhere in order to have **positive** volume gain for the synthesis or if it is a bug on the API?

Comment: DId you manage to solve it? I'm experience the same problem. It only works for values >= 0.

Comment: It's still not fixed. I have the same problem too, using Python.