# Google Text to Speech Positive Volume Gain value throws INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: java, google-text-to-speech

The current problem is that setting a positive volume gain ex: 1.00, throws the following error:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Java code to set audio config values:

```java
// Select the type of audio file you want returned
AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.newBuilder()
        .setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.valueOf("LINEAR16")) //1 for LINEAR16 - Uncompressed .WAV file format;  Sample Type: 16-bit
        .setPitch(Double.valueOf("0")) //Speaking pitch, in the range [-20.0, 20.0]. 20 means increase 20 semitones from the original pitch. -20 means decrease 20 semitones from the original pitch.
        .setSpeakingRate(Double.valueOf("1.00")) //1.0 is the normal native speed supported by the specific voice.
        .setVolumeGainDb(Double.valueOf("1.00")) //range [-96.0, 16.0]. 
        .setSampleRateHertz(Integer.valueOf("11025")) //Sample Rate: 11025 Hz
        .build();
```

This has also been reported here with no solution - [How to request synthesis with a positive volume gain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081101/how-to-request-synthesis-with-a-positive-volume-gain)